# Position parameters are different for pynput and selenium location

Tags: selenium, position, pynput

I want to find (x,y) of a button in a page that is controlled by Selenium.
1. Command find_element_by_id("id").location returns (x1,y1)
2. I use package Pynput. I put the mouse over the button and use command mouse.position (that executes from Pynput package).

```
print(driver.find_element_by_id("send_btn").location) # Returns {'x': 591, 'y': 348}
print(mouse.position) # Returns (566, 468)
```

Surprisingly, the results are very different. 
Has anybody idea about this difference?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the location and position.

Here is an example:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Something_As_An_Xpath")

print(e.position)
print(e.location)
```

Result (for your example):

```
Position -> ['width': 566, 'height': 468]
Location -> ['y': 591, 'x': 348]
```

The position is returning the width and the height of the element while the location is sending let's say the coordination of it.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.4 Elements in "FirefoxWebElement" have not "position" attribute. So, executing e.position returns error. Of course, based on your reply, I checked the following commands:

print(e.location) # This returns {'x': 565, 'y': 420}
print(e.size) # That returns {'height': 30.0, 'width': 100.0}
It seems that these two commands differ from position from Pynput

print(mouse.position) # Returns (566, 468)
So "location" is not equal to "size" nor equal to "position"

Comment: I see. I will try your code again. Delete what you wrote as an answer and keep just the comment ;)

Comment: Did you find out the reason of the difference?